# Possible To Complete This Task Using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, uml

I am creating a small app that allows the user to create class diagrams in their web browser and have so far successfully got the classes onto the screen and have the ability to add attributes and methods to the classes and now need the ability to add a connector graphic to the screen to illustrate the relationships between classes.

Are there any library's out there that have this feature. If there isn't, and i decide to write this by myself, how should i go about creating this type of feature and how difficult would you estimate the task to be?

Answer (score 0):

There is this paid library but for $6000+ i would take the time to write it myself:  http://www.jgraph.com/mxgraph.html

If you are going to develop one by yourself, a good look on these libraries should get you started:

- http://vis.stanford.edu/protovis/
- http://processingjs.org/
- http://raphaeljs.com/

I would judge this task as being pretty time-consuming. You will need to learn a lot of SVG standards in order to get started. It should be a nice ride, though :)

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's certainly possible.

Here is a link to a tool for creating SQL DB schemas (which is a little different than creating UML but it would be handy to see his approach)...

http://ondras.zarovi.cz/sql/demo/

Checking out the source files will give you an idea of the amount of code required.  It's quite a hefty project (days to weeks by the time you test it all out).  The interface for creating relations between tables is fairly nice in his demo.  It's a good tool.

Hope this helps.  Good luck with your project!